# FITS image copy and pasting, Python

Tags: python, fits

So I have a FITS image file. I want to crop one particular area (it is a straight line in the fits image which I want to copy and rotate), rotate it at an angle and then create a new image with 12 such straight lines in a circle. Like one at 30 degrees other at 60 and so on. I have tried rotating it but I don't know how do I paste it and create a new image. This is on python.

I am using this code to open the fits image:

hdul = pyfits.open('img.fits')

img=hdul[0].data

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96vo9.png)

Comment: Is the straight line in the FITS image one of 90 deg multiples (i.e., you're doing either a column or row)? Also, please share you code. We need to know what you have tried.

Comment: I have added the image from fits file. I want to crop that straight line, and then paste it in a circle. Like the hours in a clock. I haven't tried anything except for scipy rotate for rotating it. I don't know how to paste it into new image.

Comment: hdul = pyfits.open('img.fits')

img=hdul[0].data

Comment: Note that `pyfits` is very outdated. It was replaced/refactored into `astropy` several years ago.

Comment: Changed to astropy.

Comment: I have provided a generic layout as answer for your question, please have a look and take sometime to improve your requirements so that I can provide proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 1: I have edited the code based on your updated specifications.

There are three sub problems to your question:
Step 1) extracting the region you have specified.
Step 2) rotating the extracted region.
Step 3) copying it to an image(basically another numpy array).

This is still a dirty code. Can be improved based on more inputs about what to expect in input and extraction logic for feature. As of now feature extraction is still hardcoded.

```
import numpy as np
import copy
import math
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy.spatial import distance
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits


# This is for Step 1.
def extract_roi(fits_image: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """Returns the extracted region of interest(ROI) as numpy array.

    ROI: Rectangular region around white vertical line. Currently hard-coding
    the bounds. They have to be set manually.
    Assumption: ROI will be a vertical feature.
    """
    ROW_START, ROW_END = 0, 50
    COL_START, COL_END = 70, 75

    extracted_region = fits_image[ROW_START: ROW_END, COL_START:COL_END]
    return extracted_region


def square_pad_roi(roi_image, pivot):
    """ Pads the image with zeros and centers is about the pivot.

    This eases rotation about a pivot using scipy.
    Assumption: Image Top Left: Array (0, 0)
    Assumption: Image Bot Right: Array(Rows, Cols)
    :param roi_image: The image with the extracted ROI.
    :param pivot: [row, col] pivot position to rotate image about.
                  row, col should be w.r.t. roi_image co-ords.
    :return: square padded image centered about the provided pivot.
    """
    r, c = roi_image.shape[:2]
    piv_row, piv_col = pivot
    corners = [[0, 0], [0, c], [r, c], [r, 0]]  # [TL, TR, BR, BL]
    dist = math.ceil(max([distance.euclidean(x, pivot) for x in corners]))

    pad_row = [abs(piv_row - dist), abs(piv_row + dist - r)]
    pad_col = [abs(piv_col - dist), abs(piv_col + dist - c)]

    return np.pad(roi_image, [pad_row, pad_col], mode='constant',
                  constant_values=0)


# This is for Step 2.
def rotate_and_scale(image, angle, out_width) -> np.ndarray:
    """Rotates input image about center and scales it.

    :param image: ROI image input which has to be rotated.
                  Expected to be square in shaped and centered about pivot.
    :param angle: Angle in degrees to rotate image by.
    :param out_width: width in pixels to fit the image into.

    :return: rotated and scaled output image.
    """
    img = copy.deepcopy(image)
    rotated_roi = ndimage.rotate(img, angle, reshape=False)

    zoom_scale = out_width / img.shape[0]
    return ndimage.zoom(rotated_roi, zoom_scale)


# This is for Step 3.
def modify_output_image(output_image: np.ndarray,
                        rotated_roi: np.ndarray):
    """Overwrites inplace the rotated ROI image to the output image."""
    THRESHOLD = 5
    idx = np.where(rotated_roi > THRESHOLD)
    output_image[idx] = rotated_roi[idx]


# This is what you should run.
def problem_logic(input_fits_image: np.ndarray, output_width) -> np.ndarray:
    """Takes input FITS image, and returns a modified image based on usecase."""

    output_image = np.zeros((output_width, output_width))

    extracted_roi = extract_roi(input_fits_image)
    pivot = [0, extracted_roi.shape[1] // 2]  # change this based on your req.

    pivoted_roi = square_pad_roi(extracted_roi, pivot)

    # I am assuming below as your rotation logic.
    T0TAL_STEPS = 12  # For each hour orientation.
    ROTATION_STEP = float(360 / T0TAL_STEPS)  # In degrees.

    for i in range(T0TAL_STEPS):
        rotated_image = rotate_and_scale(pivoted_roi, ROTATION_STEP * i,
                                         output_width)
        modify_output_image(output_image, rotated_image)

    return output_image


def write_as_fits(image: np.ndarray, path: str):
    """ Writes the numpy image to the provided path in fits format"""
    hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(image)
    hdu.writeto(path, overwrite=True)


def driver_main():
    sample_fits = np.zeros((50, 100))
    sample_fits[:, 70:73] = 255

    # This creates the rotated ROI.
    # Replace sample_fits with your fits image.
    output_img = problem_logic(
        input_fits_image=sample_fits, output_width=400
    )

    # This writes it to output file in fits format.
    out_path = "sample.fits"
    write_as_fits(output_img, out_path)

    # This is just to visualize output.
    plt.imshow(output_img, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver_main()
```

Comment: Yes, I can improve my answer a bit more now. I will return after lunch and edit this.

Comment: Thank you so much. That would be a great help. Will wait for the answer. Also, could you please specify which things will I need to change.

Comment: That is just a sample layout, its not meant to work yet, I will change it based on your additional specs.

Comment: Did you get any chance yet? I am still waiting. :/

Comment: Sorry just got back working on it now. Give me like 15 mins.

Comment: Check it now, I am still refactoring code, writing more useful comments and cleaning up my answer.

Comment: from where do i change the input image. I have a fits image

Comment: you pass the fits image to problem_logic(), from that set the extraction boundary in the extract_roi(),  rest follow steps in order and its corresponding function, check documentation if you need to change anything or wait till I add more information to answer.

Comment: first just run this as is and let me know if that is the type of output you are expecting.

Comment: hdul = fits.open('img (15).fits')

img=hdul[0].data

and then i passed img in 

def driver_main():
    bg = np.zeros((50, 100))
    bg[:, 70:73] = 255

    output_img = problem_logic(img)
    plt.imshow(output_img, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()

But it did not change much. :(

Comment: Yes this is what I am execting. It is giving me a perfect required output. Also, is there a method to space them? So that they don't overlap on the center. Like, some distance between the center and the lower point of the pole?

Comment: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/    read the working with image data section. Your hdul will the numpy array (input image), as long as its 2 dim this will work.

Comment: in the driver main I have taken sample numpy data you should pass your hdul to the problem_logic()

Comment: You have to give the right offset as pivot to rotation. I am still modifying the code, I just pasted a dirty working code.

Comment: Try understanding the code a bit for now, I will modify the code and answer to make it more clear.

Comment: It ran. You are genius brother. Super genius!! <3

Comment: I ll wait for the offset then. Thank you soooooo much !!!

Comment: One last thing, is there a way to save this output to a fits?

Comment: Am bored that's why I am writing the whole thing, people won't do this usually, so keep that in mind while asking questions. Always ask specific questions with much detail as possible.

Comment: Sure. Thank you. Also, if you could, please tell me how do I rotate it other way. So that the lighter portion is towards the center and brighter one is away.?

Comment: You really should accept this as the answer @RitvikBasant. Seriously this is above and beyond given that all the details were not provided from the start.

Comment: Here I have changed the code a bit more. Should be easier to understand.

Comment: I tried my best to solve this without using OpenCV or scikit-image or PIL.

Comment: If this meets your requirements I would really appreciate it if you can accept this as answer. If you don't know how look at this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work